# Camera2 1440x1080 is maximum

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to display normal Full HD preview in landscape orientation (1920x1080) using `Camera2`, but camera returns 1440x1080 as the highest resolution.

With Legacy Camera (`android.hardware.camera`) there was no such issue for the same device. What am I doing wrong?

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
assert map != null;
imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

for (Size size : map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)) {
    Log.i(TAG, "imageDimension " + size);
}
```

Output:

```
imageDimension 1440x1080
imageDimension 1280x960
imageDimension 1280x720
imageDimension 864x480
imageDimension 640x640
imageDimension 832x486
imageDimension 800x480
imageDimension 720x480
imageDimension 768x432
imageDimension 640x480
```

Also it seems that to correctly display preview in landscape we need a lot of headache code like:

```
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
```

From official sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L740

Isn't Camera2 supposed to make things easier than legacy camera? I'm not sure...

Though one good thing I see: we can set many surface targets, with legacy camera we could not use `setPreviewDisplay` and `setPreviewTexture` together, but Camera2 allows many outputs

**UPDATE**

OMG!

Next information shocked me:

[image]

p.s. I have tested on Xiaomi device

[Android Camera2 Output sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362202/android-camera2-output-sizes)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/113

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/123

Comment: You write *(android.hardware.camera) there was no such issue for the same device*. Please agree the code that helped you arrive to this conclusion

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
If you have `CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY` basically your phone manufacturer does not support Camera API2.

For those who end up here as I did you can find the explanation in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362202/android-camera2-output-sizes/55442751#55442751) and this [github issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/123) .